# Add field in form with eventListener Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I need some help to understand how to use the eventListener of Symfony.
So, I have two button "add new book to sell" and "add new book to trade" in my index to steering on the same form of BookType.
My issue is : if click on "add new book to sell" path => add the price field in form.
I try [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-underlying-data) for my project but it's still not working.
Also I build a personnal form for the BookType.

Here my code for the BookType form :

```js
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)  {

        $builder->add('titreOuvrage',TextType::class,array('label'=>'Nom de l\'ouvrage','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')))
                ->add('resumeOuvrage',TextareaType::class,array('label'=>'Résumé de l\'ouvrage','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')))
                ->add('auteur', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type'=>AuteursType::class, 'allow_add'=>true, 'allow_delete'=>true))
                ->add('editeur',EntityType::class,array('label'=>'Sélectionnez l\'éditeur','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'),'class'=>'SB\MainBundle\Entity\Editeurs','choice_label'=>'libelle_editeur'))
                ->add('etat',EntityType::class,array('label'=>'Cochez l\'état dans lequel se trouve votre ouvrage','class'=>'SB\MainBundle\Entity\EtatsOuvrages','choice_label'=>'libelle_etat','expanded'=>true))
                ->add('categorie',EntityType::class,array('label'=>'Selectionnez une catégorie','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'),'class'=>'SB\MainBundle\Entity\Categories','choice_label'=>'libelle_categorie'))
                ->add('genre',EntityType::class,array('label'=>'Cochez un ou plusieurs genre','class'=>'SB\MainBundle\Entity\Genres','choice_label'=>'libelle_genre','multiple'=>true,'expanded'=>true))
//                ->add('photosOuvragePath')
                ->add('photosOuvrageFile',FileType::class,array('label'=>'Ajouter des photos'))
                ->add('statutOuvrage',EntityType::class,array('label'=>'Que voulez-vous faire de l\'ouvrage','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'),'class'=>'SB\MainBundle\Entity\StatutsOuvrages','choice_label'=>'libelle_statut'));
        // doc : http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-underlying-data
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event, Request $request) {
            //$prix = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $route = $request->attributes->get('sb_main_create_ouvrage_vente');
            // on va afficher le champ du prix seulement si on est dans le formulaire de vente
            if ($route) {
                $form->add('prixOuvrage',
                            TextType::class,
                            array('label'=>'Entrez le prix de vente','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')));
            }
        })
        ;
    }
```

Also, if it's doesn't work, I would like to know how to set a default value in a Controller function for set book => sell if click on "add new book to sell" path and book => trade if click on "add new book to trade" path.

Comment: Having to deal with form events is one reason I stopped using the Form component.  I'm fairly confident that $request is not going to be available.

Comment: Yes,$request is not available, now I know that. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put an attribute in the options array and read it in buildForm:

```
class BookType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)  {

        $builder->add('titreOuvrage',TextType::class,array('label'=>'Nom de l\'ouvrage','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')))
            ->add('resumeOuvrage',TextareaType::class,array('label'=>'Résumé de l\'ouvrage','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')))
            ->add('auteur', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type'=>AuteursType::class, 'allow_add'=>true, 'allow_delete'=>true))
            ->add('editeur',EntityType::class,array('label'=>'Sélectionnez l\'éditeur','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'),'class'=>'SB\MainBundle\Entity\Editeurs','choice_label'=>'libelle_editeur'))
            ->add('etat',EntityType::class,array('label'=>'Cochez l\'état dans lequel se trouve votre ouvrage','class'=>'SB\MainBundle\Entity\EtatsOuvrages','choice_label'=>'libelle_etat','expanded'=>true))
            ->add('categorie',EntityType::class,array('label'=>'Selectionnez une catégorie','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'),'class'=>'SB\MainBundle\Entity\Categories','choice_label'=>'libelle_categorie'))
            ->add('genre',EntityType::class,array('label'=>'Cochez un ou plusieurs genre','class'=>'SB\MainBundle\Entity\Genres','choice_label'=>'libelle_genre','multiple'=>true,'expanded'=>true))
//                ->add('photosOuvragePath')
            ->add('photosOuvrageFile',FileType::class,array('label'=>'Ajouter des photos'))
            ->add('statutOuvrage',EntityType::class,array('label'=>'Que voulez-vous faire de l\'ouvrage','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'),'class'=>'SB\MainBundle\Entity\StatutsOuvrages','choice_label'=>'libelle_statut'));

        if($options["booktype"] == "sell"){
            $builder->add('prixOuvrage',
                TextType::class,
                array('label'=>'Entrez le prix de vente','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')));
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'booktype' => 'sell',
        ));
    }
}
```

and in the controller you can call in different action routes

```
$this->createForm(BookType::class, $book, array("booktype" => "trade"));
```

or

```
$this->createForm(BookType::class, $book, array("booktype" => "sell"));
```

Comment: Have you added the line from the code above with 
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'booktype' => 'sell',
        ));
    }

Comment: Thanks, for your answer ;) . It's work for "add new book to sell" but when I click on "add new book to trade" I've this issue : Neither the property "prixOuvrage" nor one of the methods "prixOuvrage()", "getprixOuvrage()"/"isprixOuvrage()" or "__call()" exist and have public access. If I comment the div containing from.prixOuvrage in my form, it's work, but I don't want do it.

Comment: are you using the same entity for both booktypes? the book entity must also have the prixOuvrage variable

Comment: Yes I using the same entity for both. How I can have the prixOuvrage variable in this case ? Do you need my code for the book entity ?

Comment: Its not the best way to use the entity for both types of book, because you cannot differentiate between these later. for now add prixOuvrage like f.ex. titreOuvrage to the entity with getters and setters. this will be empty for books of type "trade". a good way to reuse this is to use mapped superclasses like on this link http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: and add a "required"=>true to the form field options

Comment: I have the same issue after create and use the mapped superclass.

Answer (score 0):

With using mapped superclasses you should have Entities like this:

The superclass Book

```
/**
* @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
* @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
* @ORM\Table(name="book")
*/
abstract class Book
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $titreOuvrage;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $resumeOuvrage;

//...other variables
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTitreOuvrage()
    {
        return $this->titreOuvrage;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $titreOuvrage
     */
    public function setTitreOuvrage($titreOuvrage)
    {
        $this->titreOuvrage = $titreOuvrage;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getResumeOuvrage()
    {
        return $this->resumeOuvrage;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $resumeOuvrage
     */
    public function setResumeOuvrage($resumeOuvrage)
    {
        $this->resumeOuvrage = $resumeOuvrage;
    }
}
```

The TradeBook entity which just extends the superclass:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table(name="book_tradebook")
 */
class TradeBook extends Book
{

}
```

and the SellBook entity with additional variable:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table(name="book_sellbook")
 */
class SellBook extends Book
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $prixOuvrage;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPrixOuvrage()
    {
        return $this->prixOuvrage;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $prixOuvrage
     */
    public function setPrixOuvrage($prixOuvrage)
    {
        $this->prixOuvrage = $prixOuvrage;
    }


}
```

In your FormType you can ask for the given data_class:

```
class BookType  extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)  {

        $builder->add('titreOuvrage',TextType::class,array('label'=>'Nom de l\'ouvrage','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')))
            ->add('resumeOuvrage',TextareaType::class,array('label'=>'Résumé de l\'ouvrage','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')));
            ->add('auteur', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type'=>AuteursType::class, 'allow_add'=>true, 'allow_delete'=>true))
            ->add('editeur',EntityType::class,array('label'=>'Sélectionnez l\'éditeur','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'),'class'=>'SB\MainBundle\Entity\Editeurs','choice_label'=>'libelle_editeur'))
            ->add('etat',EntityType::class,array('label'=>'Cochez l\'état dans lequel se trouve votre ouvrage','class'=>'SB\MainBundle\Entity\EtatsOuvrages','choice_label'=>'libelle_etat','expanded'=>true))
            ->add('categorie',EntityType::class,array('label'=>'Selectionnez une catégorie','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'),'class'=>'SB\MainBundle\Entity\Categories','choice_label'=>'libelle_categorie'))
            ->add('genre',EntityType::class,array('label'=>'Cochez un ou plusieurs genre','class'=>'SB\MainBundle\Entity\Genres','choice_label'=>'libelle_genre','multiple'=>true,'expanded'=>true))
//                ->add('photosOuvragePath')
            ->add('photosOuvrageFile',FileType::class,array('label'=>'Ajouter des photos'))
            ->add('statutOuvrage',EntityType::class,array('label'=>'Que voulez-vous faire de l\'ouvrage','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'),'class'=>'SB\MainBundle\Entity\StatutsOuvrages','choice_label'=>'libelle_statut'));

        if($options["data_class"] == SellBook::class){
            $builder->add('prixOuvrage',
                TextType::class,
                array('label'=>'Entrez le prix de vente','attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control')));
        }

    }


}
```

And in the controller you can use 2 actions:

```
   /**
     * @Route("/sell", name="book_sell")
     */
    public function newSellBookAction(){

        $book = new SellBook();
        $form = $this->createForm(BookType::class, $book);
        return $this->render(
            'AppBundle:book.create.html.twig',
            array("form" => $form->createView())
        );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/trade", name="book_trade")
     */
    public function newTradeBookAction(){
        $book = new TradeBook();
        $form = $this->createForm(BookType::class, $book);
        return $this->render(
            'AppBundle:book.create.html.twig',
            array("form" => $form->createView())
        );
    }
```

Comment: There is two entity at the data base creation ? Or one who have this two type ?

Comment: 3 database tables are generated, a table "book" which holds the data that both book types have in common and a "type" column which holds the information which booktype it is (defined with @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")).  the table "book_tradebook" which should only have the id from "book" and the table "book_sellbook" which has an additional column for your "prixOuvrage"

Comment: But you can f.ex. easily fetch all SellBook entities in the controller with $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(SellBook::class)->findAll();

Comment: Thanks for all. I make two forms with your first solution, and make the price nullable=true. I'ts work really find :D ! Thanks for your help !! :D !!!